# 8Bitdo SN30 Pro, does it work with linux

Tags: games, compatibility, joystick

My 8Bitdo SN30 Pro is not being detected by my computer ether by bluetooth or usb connection. Is the controller not supported in Ubuntu or Linux?

Comment: I was able to get mine recognized as an XBox controller by plugging it in via USB and following these instructions here to install the XBox drivers: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-configure-your-gamepad-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

Did you plug it via usb wire and update firmware by fwupdmgr tool?

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/update-8bitdo-firmware-linux

https://github.com/hughsie

https://fwupd.org/users